# E: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset (called "data") which contains a list of books and how they were rated by a user on an invidual level (columns = userid, isbn, book-title, book-rating).

I want to create a new features of general (aggregated) rating score and number of ratings for a book. Then I want to trimmer the dataset to contain only the books which have certain number of ratings.

I did for the number of ratings:

```
rating_count = data.groupby('Book-Title')['Book-Rating'].count().to_frame()
rating_count.rename(columns={'Book-Rating':'Rating-Count'}, inplace=True)
data = data.merge(rating_count, on='Book-Title', how='inner')
m = rating_count.quantile(.9) # trim threshols number
q_books = data.copy().loc[data['Rating-Count'] >= m] # new subsample
```

...which raises for the last row

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I randomly generated a similarly structured dataframe and run your code.

What might be raising an error is the last line of your code, specifically `... >= m]`.

`m` doesn't give you an integer or a float; it has a series type. For example, in my case `m` is:

```
Rating-Count    3.0
Name: 0.9, dtype: float64
```

`m[0]` gave me `3.0`, and hence the code worked as expected.

---

```py
# fix the last line of your code
q_books = data.copy().loc[data['Rating-Count'] >= m[0]]
```

Comment: Do you know why it does not return a numeric type for m?

Comment: @StanislavJirák according to [`pandas.DataFrame.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) documentation, it returns either `DataFrame` or `Series`, not the raw value itself. so that's basically how `.quantile` works if I understand correctly.